# Creating static resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've created a Resource Dictionary that I want to merge with multiple usercontrol xaml files. I want only one instance of this Resource Dictionary to be created. Any idea how to do this?

Note: Merge should happen through xaml only and not through code.

Thanks & Regards,
Vishal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```csharp
class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static ResourceDictionary MyResourceDictionary;

    static DictionaryExtensions()
    {
        MyResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        Style buttonStyle = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(Button) };
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.MarginProperty, new Thickness(5)));
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(5)));
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.MaxWidthProperty, 100.0d));
        MyResourceDictionary.Add("buttonStyle", buttonStyle);
    }

    public static Type GetMyDictionary(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Type)obj.GetValue(MyDictionaryProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyDictionary(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyDictionaryProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyDictionary.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDictionaryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyDictionary", typeof(Type), typeof(UserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyDictionaryChanged)));

    public static void OnMyDictionaryChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is UserControl)
        {
            (d as UserControl).Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(MyResourceDictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfSOTest.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSOTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         local:DictionaryExtensions.MyDictionary="{x:Type ResourceDictionary}">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"
                Content="Button1" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"
                Content="Button2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You can use Type object to dynamically choose between multiple dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

If it's truly global, maybe you could merge this dictionary to App.xaml?

Comment: No. It's not global. It's inside a class library and the main executable project is not aware of this Resource Dictionary.