# WPF Dynamically change resource file and theme

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

My project uses a ProjectTheme.xaml file for all WPF windows through out the project.
The ProjectTheme.xaml file references a style theme as follows

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- In order to modify the project's theme, change this line -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Customized.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

All WPF Windows references WindowBase.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/View/WindowBase.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

WindowBase.xaml references customized titlebar Bar1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Bar1.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Bar1.xaml references ProjectTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/ProjectTheme.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

So the heriarchy is

- Window1 references WindowBase.xaml
- WindowBase references Bar1.xaml
- Bar1 references ProjectTheme.xaml
- ProjectTheme.xaml reference the real theme resource file.

This works fine. 
Now I want to dynamically change the project theme at run time without quitting the app. 
Assuming that I have several theme style files

- Customized.xaml
- Customized1.xaml
- Customized2.xaml

My question is 
if it possible to dynamically update ProjectTheme.xaml file at run time to change the line 
from

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Customized.xaml" />
```

to

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Customized1.xaml" />
```

to achieve my objective?
If yes, how do I do it?
If no, what is the reason and what is the best (other) way to achieve my purpose?

I have tried the following but none of them work: the style does not change.

way 1

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Uri NewTheme = new Uri(@"/MyProject;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Customized2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(NewTheme);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

way 2

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);
Uri NewTheme = new Uri(@"/MyProject;component/Themes/WPFThemes/Customized2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(NewTheme);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, dictionary);
```

Note:
In my real theme style files (Customized.xaml...) I used a combination of dynamic resource and static resource. Does that matters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here.

First, anything defined with `StaticResource` will not get updated on a change. If you want a control to support changing the theme at runtime, you need to use `DynamicResource` so it knows to look for changes.

Your overall approach to changing the theme is correct. The easiest way to accomplish this is using [Application-scoped resource dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348820.aspx), making sure your `ResourceDictionary` is defined in your `App.xaml`. For adding a new resource, I've used snippets similar to the following:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("MyResourceDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

The part you may be confusing yourself over is when using resources within base classes. When you define a resource in a class, the resource will be local to an instance of that type. Think of the XAML compiling into it's own `InitializeComponent()` method on classes, meaning you can't change the original XAML and expect the changes to go to all instances. On the same note, changing the resources on a class instance doesn't effect other instances.

Since your question really contains two separate concerns (application theming and changing control resources), I would focus on ensuring your application resources are updating properly and using `DynamicResource`, and hopefully the information I've provided would be sufficient for understanding why certain other resources may not be updating yet.

Comment: Will, thanks for the reply. That explained why it didn't work. I didn't put the resource in App.xaml because my project is a class library that is designed to be called by a non-.net program. In this case is it still possible to change theme dynamically?

Comment: It should be possible. I haven't tried it myself, but I'd experiment with defining a static `ResourceDictionary` in code, containing your other `MergedDictionaries`, and try changing that to see if it works. Judging from other questions I've looked at, it seems that may be how others handle this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038423/creating-static-resource-dictionary

Comment: Will, your explanation get me in the right direction. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: About `DynamicResource`. How about when you define colors in *converters*? `<conv:RejectedOrMissedCallColorConverter x:Key="RejectedOrMissedCallColorConverter" MatchColor="Red" DefaultColor="{StaticResource BlackColorBrush}"/>`. I can't use *dynamic* here...