# How to assign a property in xaml to a variable inside another class?

Tags: vb.net, xaml

Lets say I have a usercontrol that is basically a button, set up in XAML. Would it be possible for that button to get its background color from a different usercontrol class in a different file, so that it is changeable during runtime?

All I found from google is talk on themes and how they all want to refer to a theme file or the main window but I didn't find either of them useful because for one, I wouldn't have the slightest idea on how to change the theme file during runtime (if its even possible) and second, I plan to use these controls I'm buildings in other projects too so i don't want them to rely on anything to do with the main window.

Answer (score 1):

Use WPF's [DynamicResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942(v=vs.110).aspx) markup extension on the button's background colour, then you can change the resource, and thus  the theme dynamically at runtime.

See the Stackoverflow answer to [WPF Dynamically change resource file and theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929013/2012417).

Answer (score 0):

All of these explain things way too confusing while the answer is as simple as pie.

step1: add a resource directory file to your project and make your variables, something like

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="lsd" />
```

step2: add to each user control you want to access the resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="myResourceName.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

stel3: make something use the resource like

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource lsd}/>
```

step4: modify the variable in the resource in any of the affected controls by calling stuff like

```
Resources("lsd") = Brushes.Blue
```

step5: for additional hilarity add a sub like this to your control

```
Public Sub lsdMode() Handles Me.MouseMove
    Dim r As New Random
    Resources("sbL1") = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255)))
End Sub
```