# Windows Forms - Update CSV resource value

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, resourcedictionary

I currently have a resource file of type CSV that I am updating via a button click.

After grabbing the new CSV from SQL server query how can I assign the new CSV as the value of my resource.

What I want (but does not work):

```
    Resources.services = getNewServices();
```

Where get new services returns a CSV file.

--UPDATE

My declaration for the file is as such
in my project 'properties/resources.rex' file:

```
    public static string clients {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("clients", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

This was automatically generated from double clicking resources.resx and manually adding a csv file (which I keep in my project folder).

Comment: How are you defining that resource file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Dynamically change resource file and theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928616/wpf-dynamically-change-resource-file-and-theme)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama thanks for the fast reply, please see my updates to the question. Thanks.